# How to calculate the hourly mean of a[NO2] column with time not in date time format but in points

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data file of almost 365 days and inside each data file, I have lots of rows but 4 columns in each file. here is a sample of my data file.

```
time:                  SZA:                       VAA:        a[NO2]:                 
 8.364470               138.00                  130.0  7.797211e+15   
 8.374150               138.12                  140.0  7.862984e+15   
 8.383833               138.24                  150.0  8.543011e+15   
 8.393519               138.36                  160.0  8.588814e+15   
 8.403200               138.48                  170.0  8.882700e+15   
 8.413137               138.61                  180.0  9.274066e+15   
 8.422819               138.73                  190.0  9.371896e+15   
 8.432500               138.85                  200.0  9.041835e+15   
 8.442184               138.97                  210.0  9.258944e+15   
 8.451867               139.09                  220.0  9.636520e+15   
 8.461547               139.21                  230.0  9.276091e+15   
 8.471230               139.33                  240.0  8.822487e+15   
 8.480911               139.45                  250.0  9.131594e+15   
8.490852               139.58                  260.0  8.602739e+15   
8.500533               139.70                  270.0  8.738126e+15   
8.510214               139.82                  280.0  8.451458e+15   
8.519883               139.94                  290.0  8.297331e+15   
8.529564               140.06                  300.0  7.688180e+15   
8.539250               140.19                  310.0  8.261479e+15   
8.548933               140.31                  320.0  8.713488e+15   
8.558617               140.43                  330.0  8.044735e+15   
8.568806               140.56                  340.0  7.753632e+15   
8.578995               140.69                  350.0  8.521977e+15   
8.588677               140.81                  360.0  8.258493e+15   
9.189353               148.54                  130.0  4.993639e+15   
9.199036               148.67                  140.0  5.009416e+15   
9.208719               148.79                  150.0  5.087714e+15   
9.218394               148.92                  160.0  5.337511e+15   
9.228072               149.05                  170.0  5.739801e+15   
9.238000               149.18                  180.0  6.126621e+15
```

..         ...                  ...                    ...           ...

How can I calculate the 'hourly mean of a[NO2] column'? Also how the time series plot looks like (time vs hourly mean of a[NO2]?
Here is my code:

```
time=[]
NO2=[]
for horizon_2020 in horizon_filepaths:
    horizon_data = pd.read_csv(horizon_2020, usecols=[1,4,6,13], sep ='\s+', header = 63)
    for i in range(7,16):
        NO2_mean=horizon_data.loc[(horizon_data['time']>=i) & (horizon_data['time']<(i+1)), 'a[NO2]'].mean()  
        time_mean=horizon_data.loc[(horizon_data['time']>=i) & (horizon_data['time']<(i+1)), 'time'].mean()
        time.append(time_mean)
        NO2.append(NO2_mean)
plt.scatter(time,NO2)
plt.title('HORIZON NO$_2$ OVER BREMEN') 
plt.xlabel('time(UTC)') 
plt.ylabel('NO$_2$ SC hourly mean(molecules/cm$^2$)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you dont know what the unit of time is in this dataset, how could we? You need to ask the source

Comment: time is in UTC i.e. Universal Coordinated time

Comment: @adventurouslife can you provide a link with the complete CSV file for me to test the code? Also, do you have a different file for every 24 hours? and if so do you want the plot for each day or a cumulative plot for the year?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will give you a general idea. I did not have the actual csv file so I don't know how you handle different dates etc. Nevertheless it should give you a general idea on the problem.

```py
def findFiles(name: str, ext: str, path='./'):
    """
    Finds all the files matching the criteria specified

    :param path: the directory of the file. Default value current directory
    :param name: the name of the file. For multiple files with same part of the name use same_part *
    :param ext: the extension (type) of the file e.g. .txt, .svg Don't forget the dot
    :return: a list with all the files found
    """
    files = []
    for file_path in glob.glob(path + name + ext):
        files.append(open(file_path, 'r'))

    return files


if __name__ == '__main__':

    hourly_mean_NO2_value = []

    # this function will get all the csv files that start with horizon_data_ in the directory you want
    # (here the ./ is the directory of the script)
    horizon_file_paths = findFiles('./', 'horizon_data_*', '.csv')

    for horizon_2020 in horizon_file_paths:

        # create the data frame from the csv file. Only the columns time and a[NO2] are read
        # horizon_data is a pandas dataFrame containing only the two columns 'time:' and 'a[NO2]:'
        horizon_data = pd.read_csv(horizon_2020, usecols=['time:', 'a[NO2]:'], sep=',', header=0)

        # Get the first value for time
        start_time = float(horizon_data.iloc[0][0])

        NO2 = []

        for index, row in horizon_data.iterrows():
            # find the time difference
            passed_time = float(row['time:']) - start_time

            # if the time difference is less that one we just append the a[NO2] value
            if passed_time <= 1.0:
                NO2.append(int(row['a[NO2]:']))

            # when the time difference is more than 1 hour...
            elif passed_time >= 1.0:
                # ... we reset the start time...
                start_time = float(row['time:'])
                # ... calculate the average ...
                NO2_avg = sum(NO2) / len(NO2)
                # ... append the average ...
                hourly_mean_NO2_value.append(NO2_avg)
                # ... and finally clear the NO2 list so that we can save the next hour values
                NO2.clear()

        for num in hourly_mean_NO2_value:
            # prints the number is scientific notation
            print('{:.6e}'.format(num))
```

As for the plot I did not have enough data to create one but it should look something like a stock value over time.